# Couple of questions about System Tray Minimize - WIN API

Tags: c, windows, winapi, system-tray

I want to minimize my program to the system tray, and then I have 3 things I want the program to do :

1) If I'll put my mouse on it, it'll show some text near it(like when u put a mouse near the Internet Icon and it tells you you'r Network SSID...
2) If I'll right click on the icon in the system tray, X will happen
3) if I'll left click on the icon in the system tray, Y will happen

I minimize my program to the system tray using this code :

```
void MinimizeSystemTray(HWND hwnd)
{
NOTIFYICONDATA nid; 
nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid); 
nid.hWnd = hwnd;
nid.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION); 
nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER; 
nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE; 

ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
}
```

It works great, though I couldent find solution for the 3 problems I had...

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to handle the messages that the shell will send you.  Use the [SDK sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/shellintegration), NotifyIcon.zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation more carefully.  Everything you are asking for is covered by it.

You are already using `NIF_TIP` and `NIF_MESSAGE`, which allow you to provide the popup text on mouse hover (#1), and tell the System Tray what window message to send back to your HWND when the user clicks on your icon (#2 and #3), respectively.  That message contains all the information you need to know to differentiate between mouse hovering vs left/right mouse buttons vs spacebar key pressing.

Comment: Thank you very much! The last problem I have occured was how to make the small "menu option" if you normally right click on program's icons...
I just coudlent understand how to do it... May you please show me a small code of explanaition? Thanks!

Comment: The documentation is very clear about that. The icon will send your `HWND` the `uCallbackMessage` message containing either a `WM_CONTEXTPOPUP` or `WM_RBUTTONUP` notification when the icon is right-clicked (depending on Shell version and whether you use `NIM_SETVERSION`) or a `NIN_KEYSELECT` notification if the icon is selected with the keyboard, then you can display your popup menu as needed, such as with `TrackPopupMenu/Ex()`.